# Substitute for sugar/golden syrup as binding agent in breakfast bars for kids

Tags: substitutions

I found [this recipe](http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/1605/ontherun-breakfast-bars) for breakfast bars, and I would like to make some ahead of time and then give them to the kids on the go, to make mornings easier.  As my kids will be eating these most days, I want to remove the sugar as much as possible.

First question:  what is the binding agent in these?  Is it the sugar or the syrup, or something else?

Second question:  if I wanted to remove the added sugar (to [Weetabix levels](http://www.foodforliving.ie/sugar-content-of-your-favourite-cereals/)), what is another binding agent I could use?  I see some people using [banana](http://www.thekitchn.com/recipe-4-ingredient-banana-oat-bars-snack-recipes-from-the-kitchn-156571), but I would like some other options as one of the girls struggles when she eats too much banana.

Comment: Is reducing calories, or refined sugar especially, or sugar in any form your desired goal?

Comment: Refined sugar primarily, but all sugar would be good.

Answer (score 2):

The syrup and the oats appear to be the binding agents in your recipe. If you don't plan on omitting the golden syrup no substitution is necessary. If you want to do away with the golden syrup, coconut oil is commonly used in vegan protein bar recipes as the binder. Another way would be to add some "sticky fruits" (like dried dates or raisins)

Answer (score 2):

If you can find Yacon syrup, it is the healthiest sugar substitute and great for replacing syrups. It does not spike blood sugar or even register any blood sugar reaction and is loaded with FOS which friendly gut bacteria feast on.

Comment: Suggesting a sugar substitute and describing concrete differences, as you did, is good here. Making a blanket claim as to whether it is healthier or not is considered off topic.